# Syntax Error when creating a function (that doesn't work) in Python

Tags: python

```
def guessr(inpt):
  guess = input("type something: ")
  print(guess)
  if type(guess) == str:
    print("is a string")
  elif type(guess) == int or type(guess) == float:
    print("is a number")
  else:
    print("i don't know")
  return()

def guessr(67)
```

Hi guys, can you help me? This code doesn't run and i receive this error:

```
file "main.py", line 12
def guessr(67)
syntax error: invalid syntax
```

maybe is just a problem of python's version, because i'm use to program in python2.7 and this compiler is in python3 , but i can't understand my mistake

thank u for the help

Comment: Don't use `def` when calling the function, only when defining it.

Comment: Why you have a `def guessr(67)` at the end ? Just call `guessr(67)`. `def` is used to define a `function/method`

Comment: Invalid syntax aside, I also want to point out that your function won't work as you will always receive a `str` from input. You will need a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just call the function with the name, no need to use `def` when calling an already declared function. There is no issue of the version of python you use. It works the same in both `python2.7` or `python3`.

```
def guessr(inpt):
  guess = input("type something: ")
  print(guess)
  if type(guess) == str:
    print("is a string")
  elif type(guess) == int or type(guess) == float:
    print("is a number")
  else:
    print("i don't know")
  return()

guessr(67)
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: @Barmar only if you have patience for at least a min or so.

Comment: This was a trivial typo, IMHO, not really worth a full-blown answer just to say "don't write `def` when calling the function"

Comment: first of all, it was not a typo, and second thing how does it even matter if a full answer is given or not. I felt like giving in the full explanation as he is a newbie so I did. Why are you bothered!!!

Comment: Answers make it harder for the question to be auto-deleted after being closed.

Comment: don't worry about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189696/discussion-between-rahil-hastu-and-barmar).